# php loop curl - echo data

Tags: php, curl, foreach, jsondecoder

I need help as a PHP newbie! :D

We are trying to map data about our members for our clan via the open API of "gametools.network".

I would like to query this as a loop for several members at the same time and already have a good basic.

Unfortunately I don't know why I can't echo the data from the string.

Can someone help me here?

```
<?php

// skip_battlelog allows you to skip battlelog when it searches a name
// available options: true, false
$skip_battlelog = 'true';

// available options: de-de, en-us
$lang = 'de-de';

// available options: stats, weapons, vehicles, all
$stats = 'stats';

// available options: pc, ps4, xboxone
$platform = 'ps4';

// available options: bf4, bf1, bfv
$game = 'bfv';

// player psn-id
$psid1 = 'WODAN-HRAFNAGUD';
$psid2 = 'DerTobe';

// Run POST Request via CURL
$url1 = "https://api.gametools.network/$game/$stats/?format_values=true&name=$psid1&platform=$platform&lang=$lang&skip_battlelog=$skip_battlelog";
$url2 = "https://api.gametools.network/$game/$stats/?format_values=true&name=$psid2&platform=$platform&lang=$lang&skip_battlelog=$skip_battlelog";

$sites = [$url1,$url2];
$data = [];
foreach ($sites as $site) {

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $site);

    // User agent
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "PHP Curl");

    // Include header in result? (0 = yes, 1 = no)
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    // Should cURL return or print out the result? (true = return, false = print)
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Timeout in seconds
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

    // execute the given URL, and return output
    $data[] = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);
    
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
echo  '</pre>';

var_dump($data);

?>

<h2>Username: <? echo ($data[0]['userName']);?></h2>

<h2><img src="<? echo ($data['avatar']);?>" width="20px" height="auto" /> <? echo ($data['userName']);?></h2>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Rang:</td>
    <td><? echo ($data['rank']);?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>K/D:</td>
    <td><? echo ($data['killDeath']);?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>SPM:</td>
    <td><? echo ($data['scorePerMinute']);?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Kills:</td>
    <td><? echo ($data['kills']);?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Kopfschüsse:</td>
    <td><? echo $data['headShots'] ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Höchste Killstreak:</td>
    <td><? echo ($data['highestKillStreak']);?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Präzision:</td>
    <td><? echo ($data['accuracy']);?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Beste Klasse:</td>
    <td><? echo ($data['bestClass']);?></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: add exit() after var_dump($data); and then check either you got your desired data or not

Comment: To start with curl_exec does not return an array, this will be just the raw output; JSON, XML or whatever. So you'll need to parse that data so you get an array. Also you won't be able to access `$data['killDeath']` because from what I can see it will never exist. If you're not seeing any errors put `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at the top of the file. This might help you understand where you're going wrong